# Time complexity of algorithm with three loops and if statement

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, algorithm-analysis, big-o-notation

Suppose I have this c++ code:

```
for(int i=0; i<n*n*n; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<n*n; j++) {
            if(i>n && j<n) {
                for(int k=0; k<n*n*n*n; k++) s++;
            }
        }
    }
```

I need to find its time complexity.

What I tried doing is: I tried determining the times the if clause would be fulfilled, and multiplying that with $n^4$.

However, I have a hard time determining how many times the if clause will be fulfilled. The values of `i` go from $n+1$ to $n^3-1$, while the values for `j` go from $0$ to $n-1$.

Now, for each value of `i` for which the first part of the condition is true, I have that there are $n$ values of `j` for it.

Unfortunately, this is as far as I have come. Could anyone help me out further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's divide it in two parts: when the code enters the **if** and when it does not.

1. The **if** is executed when $n<i<n^3$ and $0\leq j <n$. This means that the values of $i$ which satisfy the condition are $n^3-n-1$, while the values of $j$ which satisfy the condition are $n-1$. For each value of $i$ for which the condition on it is satisfied you can choose every values of $j$ which satisfies the condition of it and viceversa. It means that the **if** is executed $(n^3-n-1)(n-1) = \Theta(n^4)$ times. In these cases the inner-most loop is executed $n^4$ times and each execution has a constant cost. So, the total cost of this case is $\Theta(n^4\cdot n^4)=\Theta(n^8)$.
2. In the remaining cases, i.e. $\approx n^5-n^4=\Theta(n^5)$ times, the **if** is not executed and the cost of one iteration the two outer-most loops is constant (just a check on the **if** condition), thus the cost of this case is $\Theta(n^5)$.

Summing up, the total cost is:
$$\Theta(n^8)+\Theta(n^5)= \Theta(n^8) \ .$$

PS: If you are not familiar with asymptotic notation, look at it (big-O, Theta, Omega, small-o notations or Landau symbols). You can consider $\Theta(n^i)$ as $\approx n^i$ while reading this answer. Then I suggest you to go check these topics.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately I have gotten it wrong, here's what I did:

If i=n+1, then there are j=0,j=1...j=n-1 values for which the condition is satisfied. Then, if i=n+2 the same applies. What I did was find the sum of all natural numbers from n+1 to n^3 and multiplied that with n-1 and I got a polynomial of the seventh power. I did this because I thought that **since there are n+1 values for each value of "i"**.